# How can I change my SVG path to the specification below?

Tags: html, svg

How can I change my SVG path to width: 7.58 and height: 16.62. (7.58x16.62)?

My SVG icon is 19x19px but I'm looking to change the SVG PATH to width: 7.58 and height: 16.62.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 19px;
  height: 19px;
}

div {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M1.01099 5.36841L8.42124 12.5263L16.2215 5.36841" stroke="#111111" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

Currently my SVG path size is 15.21x7.16 and I need to make the svg path size width: 7.58 and height: 16.62.

![jsfiddle svg path incorrect should be the other way around, with the correct values][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1InxN.png

Comment: I would recommend not working with fractional pixel values as browser engines will probably render the result differently. On a side note, what happens if you change both the dimensions and the viewBox to use a value of 19px? Seems to render well here, but I might be missing your point? `<svg width="19" height="19" viewBox="0 0 19 19" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1.01099 5.36841L8.42124 12.5263L16.2215 5.36841" stroke="#111111" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/></svg>`

Comment: Are you sure you really want a width of 7.58? Then of course the chevron is cut (and makes no sense to have a height so large)

Comment: You have the height and width the wrong way round. The path coordinated go: ` L x y` so each x value must be smaller than your width. Currently the width is set to ~8 and you have an x coordinate of 16. It helps to put spaces in your path definition: `d="M 1.01099 5.36841 L 8.42124 12.5263 L 16.2215 5.36841"`

Comment: Hey @agrm, in chrome I get a path of 15.21 x 7.16

Comment: look into this now thank you @DavePritlove

Comment: @DavePritlove  I put the updated code of `<svg height="16.62" width="7.58" viewBox="0 0 16.62 7.58" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M 1.01099 5.36841 L 8.42124 12.5263 L 16.2215 5.36841" stroke="#111111" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>` and I get an svg path of 17.39 x 8.18 but the bottom of the icon looks cut off? I posted a pic in the original post.

Comment: @User101 I'd missed that the second y coordinate is 12.5. Basically your width has to be greater than the greatest x coordinate and the height greater than the greatest y coordinate. Also, line widths are measured from centre of the coordinate so you need at least 0.5 line width added to the max x and max y coordinate. Capital L means "line-to (absolute) coordinate x y" and forms a line from the previous point. You should be able to plot it out on paper and construct the path you want. Use spaces, they're allowed an make it much easier to visualise x y.

Answer (score 1):

The `svg` path definition `d` uses coordinates to plot a path. For a path made of straight line segments, the coordinates are preceeded with an instruction letter (M or m, L or l) with capitals denoting that absolute coordinates follow (small letters indicate relative coordinates). M denotes "move to", L denotes "(draw) line to".

So the coordinates of the line must lie within the bounds of the width and height distances (assuming the viewbox is set to the same width and height as the image).

I've approximated to your svg in the working snippet here. (it's blown up by fitting it 100% to a sized container but will render to 17x17 without the container or css width set). I've used rounded numbers to simplify the path.

If you're constructing the path yourself, always use spaces. They're allowed and they make it easier to see what you've done. The pattern is:

```
d="M x y L x y L x y"
```

You can plot simple images on squared paper and read coordinates.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 170px;
  height: 170px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<svg width="17" height="17" viewBox="0 0 17 17" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"> <path d="M 1 5 L 8 13 L 16 5" stroke="#111111" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/> </svg>
</div>
```

Lastly, bear in mind lines widths are calculated from the centre of the coordinate they meet, so allow at least 0.5 line width on top of the maximum coordinate in both directions.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer I really appreciate it. I'm trying to replicate an svg path of 7.58x16.62. I have updated my post to make it more clear. Thank you for your time once again

Comment: @User101 A chevron shape pointing downwards (if that is what you want) will always be wider than it is high, unless you change the angle of the point to make a very deep V shape. You can render a chevron shaped like yours into space occupied by 7.58 width only by making the whole shape smaller and showing it with gaps above and below. Can you draw on paper exacly what you want, with a border  and the sizes to the box and the height an width of the chevron, and post a photo of it. Make sure to include the chevron and the box surrounding it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly control the size of an SVG path as it is dictated by the boundaries of the path itself. What you can do is scale the path to achieve the desired size:

`scale x factor: 7.58 / 15.21 = 0.4983563445101907`

`scale y factor: 16.62 / 7.16 = 2.32122905027933`

```
svg path {
    transform: scale(0.4984, 2.3212)
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution makes the chevron go out of place

Comment: @User101 that's because you need to adjust the SVG `viewBox` to fit the path.